# Estimation of unit-root AR(1) model with OLS

Tags: least-squares, assumptions, autoregressive, unit-root, random-walk

Given a random walk $x_t$,

$$x_t=x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t,$$

consider estimating the slope coefficient $\beta$ in

$$x_t=\beta x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$$

by OLS. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143810/random-walk-estimation-with-ar1) question and the following answer noted that $\hat \beta^{OLS}$ has a skewed distribution. My **question** is,

Are any of OLS assumptions violated in the model $x_t=\beta x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$ given that $x_t$ is a random walk? If so, what are the violations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is generally assumed that the explanatory variables have finite moments at least up to second order. In this case, as the explanatory variable is a random walk, its variance is not finite. This makes the matrix $Q=\hbox{plim } X′X/n$ not finite, with the consequences discussed below.

The explanatory variable $x_{t-1}$ is not fixed (it is stochastic as it depends on $\epsilon$) and is not independent of the error term $\epsilon_t$. This makes OLS in general biased and inference is not valid in small samples.

The explanatory variable and $\epsilon_t$ are not independent of each other but they are contemporaneously uncorrelated, $E(x_t, u_t) = 0 \forall t$. In the classical regression model this will open the possibility for the the OLS estimator to be consistent in large samples.

If the matrix $Q = \hbox{plim } X′X/n$ were finite and positive definite matrix, then the F-test statistic will follow asymptotically follows the $\chi^2$ distribution. 
As pointed by @ChristophHanck this matrix is not finite in this context. Hence, the [Mann and Wald theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) is not applicable and inference based on OLS will not be reliable even in large samples.

You may be interested in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133757/arq-model-with-f-test/133805#133805), which discusses similar issues in the context of a stationary AR(q) process.

Comment: I think "$Q=plim X'X/n$ not finite" is kind of what I was looking for. I just figured that out independently, and now I see it in your answer.

Comment: I am little confused here. In the case of a random walk where we try to estimate the equation $X_{t+1} = \beta X_t + \epsilon$, due to the cointegrating realtionsip $X_{t+1} - X_t$ we should converge at the superconsistent rate to $\beta =1$. Why do you think we are not going to have any reliable results?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc you are right, OLS will in general be consistent. (Phillips (1987) Theorem 3.1). I have edited the answer referring only to problems with inference.

Answer (score 6):

One of the key assumptions I would list among standard OLS assumptions is that there is no weak LLN for the "average of the $X'X$-matrix" $1/T\sum_tx_{t-1}^2$. Instead, we have weak convergence to a functional of Brownian motion provided we scale by $T^2$, viz.

$$
T^{-2}\sum_{t=1}^Tx^2_{t-1}\Rightarrow\sigma^2\int_0^1W(r)^2d r
$$

I would, btw, not quite agree with @Alecos statement in the link you posted that there is no analytical solution to the distribution of the OLSE - we know the asymptotic distribution of the OLSE, when scaled with the suitable superconsistent rate $T$, to be

\begin{eqnarray*}
T\left(\hat{\beta}^{OLS}-1\right)&=&T\frac{\sum_{t=1}^Tx_{t-1}\epsilon_{t}}{\sum_{t=1}^Tx_{t-1}^2}\\
&=&\frac{T^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^Tx_{t-1}\epsilon_{t}}{T^{-2}\sum_{t=1}^Tx_{t-1}^2}\\
&\Rightarrow&\frac{\sigma^2/2\{W(1)^2-1\}}{\sigma^2\int_0^1W(r)^2d r}\\
&=&\frac{W(1)^2-1}{2\int_0^1W(r)^2d r},
\end{eqnarray*}
the "Dickey-Fuller-distribution" (JASA 1979).

Comment: Your answer is useful in that it helps to understand what is going wrong, but it does not directly answer the question. What about pinning down a specific assumption that is being violated?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if we knew precisely what the OLS assumptions are to you. Take eg assumption 8.3(c) in Hamilton, which requires (translated to our notation) $E(x_{t-1}^2)$ to exist and $1/T\sum_tx_{t-1}^2$ to converge to it. Neither is the case here.

Comment: Fair remark. I should have spelled out the assumptions in the OP. But this comment as well as the answer by @javlacalle partly does the job for me and are quite helpful. I was picking more on your formulation, not on the content.

Comment: That was a helpful answer (+1), thank you! (My earlier comments may or may have not come across right.)