# What errorbars to use when plotting the difference between two medians?

Tags: error, median

I am trying to plot the difference between two medians. When I plot each median separately, I am using median absolute deviation as my error. However, I don't know what error I should use when I take the difference between the two medians.

Let me know if I can provide more information. Thanks!

Comment: Are you estimating a standard error for the difference between the medians somehow?  Are you estimating a confidence interval for the difference b/t the medians?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45124 for formulas for the standard error of the median.  Research "notched boxplot" for one classic solution.  To avoid pitfalls, consider the unusual situations discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/407746/919.