# Properties of OLS under non-stationary variables

Tags: stationarity, spurious-correlation, gauss-markov-theorem

I estimate the following equation using OLS:
$y_{t} = a + b*x_{t} + u_t$.
I performed ADF tests for both y and x series and found that H0 (the existence of unit root) can not be rejected. I also performed ADF test for residuals $\hat{u}_t$ and got the same result. $R^2 > 0.9$ and t-stat for $\hat{b}$ is sufficiently greater than zero.

I remembered from my university courses that regressing non-stationary variables lead to spurious regression: t-stat is meaningless and no longer follows t-distribution and $\hat{b}$ is not consistent. The only exception is the case of cointegrated variables.

The question is: exactly which assumptions of Gauss-Markov theorem are violated? Why the $\hat{b}$ is not consistent? Why we can’t just adjust $\hat{Var}(\hat{b})$ using standard errors in the Newey-West form to have consistent estimates of standard errors of coefficients in the case of heteroscedasticity and serial correlation?

Comment: Is $x_t$ really stochastic or is it just increasing (e.g., a time trend-type variable)?  It makes some difference for the asymptotics...

Comment: This is likely a duplicate question (at least the first two out of three questions). Consider searching the website carefully to find a thread that answers it.

Comment: $y_t$ looks like slightly deformed part of sinus and $x_t$ has no clear trend and looks like really stochastic.

Comment: One example for the types of available answers @RichardHardy mentioned: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145864/estimation-of-unit-root-ar1-model-with-ols